# How to create a Reload function for language change in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization

I have used a library called react-native-localization to translate my app. I have two languages, Arabic and English. I have created a settings page which handles the manual language selection. Everything works fine in the body of the screens, the headers and Items in the English version. The problem is that translations doesn't take affect in navigator headers or Items as they do in the contents of the screens themselves in Arabic. But when I change the device language everything gets translated as they should, not only the screens themselves but all of the headers, items and etc. I want to change the language for all of the contents of the app without changing the device language.

I have tried many ways and many libraries. There is this one thing that I experienced when changing some styles while my Live reload and Hot reload was on and the language selected manually was Arabic. What happened was that when I changed the styles, app reloaded without restarting and headers and items got translated too. But when I restarted the app, the problem came back. I tried to create the same functionality that happened and I was successful but when I restarted the app the problem came back like last time.
If you know anyway to solve this, please help.

Comment: Does `location.reload(true);` not work for you?